# dkms build error when tried to install Wi-Fi drivers

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers, dkms

So I am trying to install Wi-Fi drivers as part of my Wi-Fi not working issue. I am following this answer: [Installing Wi-Fi driver for Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device [10ec:d723]](https://askubuntu.com/a/988947/1365479) for the purpose, but on the command:

`sudo dkms build rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414`

I am getting the following error:

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=5.4.0-113-generic.....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-113-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
```

Please help me regarding this.

I am also facing another issue. My Wi-Fi works fine for some time after rebooting, but after half an hour or so it starts showing *no internet* and when I turn off and on my Wi-Fi, it then shows *no wifi adapter found*.

Answer (score 0):

The [repository you're trying to build from](https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de) has not been updated since year 2017, and at that time, 4.11 was the newest kernel version available. There is no guarantee whatsoever that a driver from that repository will work with any kernel version newer than 4.11.

Your system has kernel version 5.4, which was released in late 2019.

[Here is another repository for the rtl8723 driver](https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de), which seems to have been updated to support newer kernels, at least up to version 5.8. If you have to stay with your current kernel, you might try using this updated repository instead.

Also note that your current kernel version has a `rtw88` driver as part of the standard kernel, but unfortunately in kernel version 5.4 it doesn't yet support the Realtek RTL8723DE chip. [The support was apparently added in May 2020](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88?h=v5.10.119&id=f5df1a8b4376551f7fb2416135c58896b70a1467), which means kernel version 5.7 at the earliest, unless the support was backported. If you can consider upgrading your kernel, I might recommend upgrading to the next long-term supported kernel version 5.10. Its `rtw88` driver should support your WiFi without relying on third-party drivers from external repositories.